# Input from keyboard into Class

Tags: c#, class, console

This Code work well:

```
kwadrat kw = new kwadrat();
int k;

try
{
    k = 2;
    kw.X = k;
}
```

but when i want to take `kw.X` from keyboard like this:

```
try
{
    k = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadKey());
    kw.X = k;
}
```

I have an error on converting. Why ?

Comment: What is the error exactly? By the way, are you sure you don't wanna use `Console.ReadLine` instead?

Comment: What is the error? Convert.ToInt32 will only work for numeric 0-9 as input argument

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type'System.ConsoleKeyInfo' on type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: nvm, i forgot about 'Console.ReadLine' thanks guys. Now it's ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the return type of [ReadKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx).

It returns a type `ConsoleKeyInfo` that cannot be cast to Int

Comment: I must use `Console.ReadLine()` and I forgot about it. Thanks for answer.

Comment: No problem. Glad you figured it out so soon.